# Understanding node `tmp` package

Tags: javascript, node.js, tmp

I'm not sure how to use the tmp package of node correctly. Maybe someone can give me an example

**Filename generation**

> It is possible with this library to generate a unique filename in the
>   specified directory.

```
var tmp = require('tmp');

tmp.tmpName(function _tempNameGenerated(err, path) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Created temporary filename: ", path);
});
```

But what and how do I pass `path`. As I understand it, it makes sure, that in my desired directory are just unique filenames. So do I have to pass my for example upload directory as path? (But how syntax wise?)

[Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tmp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

You call `tmpName`, it calls its callback with an error (`err`, `null` if there isn't one) and the path.

Inside the callback you do what you want to do with the temporary filename, like write something to it.